# jQuery's triggering a click doesn't preserve the set pageX and pageY values

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'd like to be able to manually click a HTML5 Canvas element in my application with given `(x, y`) coordinates. That said, I'm able to trigger the `click` event, however, the event's `pageX` and `pageY` coordinates always come back `0`.

```
// the always prints out 0, 0
window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.pageX, e.pageY);
});


// triggering of action based on random X, Y coords
const action = new $.Event('click', {
  pageX: Math.random() * window.innerWidth,
  pageY: Math.random() * window.innerHeight
});
this.$canvas.trigger(action);
```

Comment: Try `body` instead of `window`.

Comment: As in `document.body.addEventListener`? If so, same problem persists.

Comment: For me in Chrome it works as in your `code`.

Comment: Can you please show me a JSFiddle? Because it doesn't work at all for me

Comment: I just pasted it into the `console`. BRB with the Fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/1hjsgmn9/.

Comment: Thank you, @AjAX. You provided me a hint. The issue was that it's need to be same element. Answer posted below.

Comment: Ah. Seen. Did — not — look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Need to ensure the item you're triggering the `event` to matches the item you're attaching an event listener to. For example:

```
const $canvas = $('canvas');

$canvas.on('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.pageX, e.pageY);
});

// triggering of action based on random X, Y coords
$canvas.trigger($.Event('click', {
  pageX: Math.random() * window.innerWidth,
  pageY: Math.random() * window.innerHeight
}));
```